# Acceleration from Velocity

Tags: calculus, physics

How would you find the acceleration of an automobile at $t$ seconds from the formula giving velocity $v(t)$ in $ft/sec$:

$$v(t) = \frac{85t}{6t+16}$$

$5$ seconds ? _____$ft/sec^2$

$10$ seconds ? _____$ft/sec^2$

$20$ seconds ? _____$ft/sec^2$

Do I use the formula:

$$a = \frac{v_1 - v_0}{t_1-t_0}$$

or

$$a = \frac{340}{(3t+8)^2}$$

Thanks,

-

**Update 1**—According to comments, I should use the first derivative of the velocity equation. The answers I calculated are $.643, .235$, and $.074$. Would I need to divide by seconds?

**Update 2**—Thanks for all your help. The aforementioned values were correct! :D

Comment: Acceleration is the first derivative of the velocity with respect to time.

Comment: @MarioG No, acceleration is the *second* derivative of the position (displacement) wrt time, and the *first* derivative of the velocity wrt time.

Comment: @Deepak Oh yes, you're right!

Comment: So would I use the derivative a = 340 / (3t-8)^2 to obtain the answer? And would I divide by t, or the amount of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that instead of simply applying formulas, you strengthen your concepts first.

The first equation you quoted:

$$a = \frac{v_1 - v_0}{t}$$

only applies in the case of a constant acceleration.

The acceleration here is *not* constant.

To find it you'll need to apply the more general rule:

$$a = \frac{dv}{dt}$$

which means differentiating the expression for velocity that you're given.

Comment: The answers I got were: .643, .235, .074 respectively. Would I need to divide by seconds?

Comment: @CE7 That looks about right. Assuming the velocity formula was given in units of $ft/sec$ the units of the acceleration you computed should be $ft/sec^2$ as required. Nothing further required.

Answer (score 0):

Just differentiate your velocity vector V(t) to get A(t) .Plug in 5,10,15 to get answer